# How to wrap _Rendezvous future returned by grpc

Tags: python, grpc, future

I wanted to implement retry logic with interceptors in python for grpc clients.

if we want to implement it for async calls of grpc, it gets tricky a little bit. we know that we can get an async grpc call like this:

```py
future_response = stub.SayHello.future(SayHelloRequest())
```

so if i want to implement a retry logic i need to check if the future had an exception or not:

```
future_response.exception()
```

Actually we cant do this, since it gets block until the response come.
So we need to use `add_done_callback` method of returned future. so to do this i need a way to wrap returuned future by grpc call but i dont know any safe way to do it. the type of object returned by async grpc call is `_Rendezvous`, i need to wrap this object with another `_Rendezvous` future so i can call `set_result` on that manually in the callback of main future. but i couldnt find a proper way or any helper function in grpc codes to let me do this.

Comment: `_Rendezvous` is a concrete implementation of `RpcError` and `RpcContext`. Neither of these interfaces provides you a way to extract the request payload that failed, so "wrapping" this object is not what you want to do in order to retry the RPC. Instead, you should somehow keep track of the request that needs to be resent and start a new RPC.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap it using the following function:

```
import asyncio

def wrap_grpc_future(grpc_future, loop=None):
    """Wrap grpc.Future into awaitable asyncio Future."""

    if asyncio.isfuture(grpc_future):
        return grpc_future
    if loop is None:
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    future = loop.create_future()

    def done(grpc_future):
        try:
            if grpc_future.cancelled():
                future.cancel()

            if not future.cancelled():
                e = grpc_future.exception()
                if e:
                    future.set_exception(e)
                else:
                    future.set_result(grpc_future.result())

        except Exception as e:
            future.set_exception(e)

    grpc_future.add_done_callback(done)

    return future
```

also there is a new [gRPC AsyncIO API](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc_asyncio.html) but documentation is scarce.